# Lifetime of primitive/object value when it's returned from a function

Tags: c++

```
class Foo {
private:
    int num;
    std::string str;

public:
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs) {
        this->num = rhs.num;
        this->str = rhs.str;
        return *this;
    }

    Foo& operator+(const Foo& rhs) {
        Foo tmp(this->num + rhs.num, this->str + rhs.str);
        return tmp;
    }
};
```

If I write a code like `Foo f3; f3 = f1 + f2;`, runtime error occurs when `this->str = rhs.str;` in **operator=()** is executed.

I think temporary std::string object(`this->str + rhs.str`) made in **operator+()** is regional so it is removed when the function call is finished. But int value(`this->num + rhs.num`) is passed well without problems.

Why is this difference happening?

Comment: What is the runtime error you are getting? Did you debug the values?

Comment: A "typical" operator+ will return Foo by value (without the &). Your code returns a reference to a temporary Foo.

Comment: You're returning a reference to a temporary. Don't do that. And take a look at the canonical forms of the [arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) for guidance on the correct prototype.

Comment: There's a difference because you made `operator+()` return a reference, which (a) it shouldn't do and (b) **no** function should do if the reference is to a local variable. Just don't do that. It has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Oh, and you should really turn on all your compiler's warnings.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already correctly asserted that `tmp` is only local to `Foo::operator+` and thus the returned reference is invalid (a dangling reference).

> But int value(this->num + rhs.num) is passed well without problems.

I think you refer to code like this:

```
int operator+(const Foo& rhs) {
   int tmp(this->num + rhs.num);
   return tmp;
}
```

Yes, that works. Notice the important difference that `int operator+(const Foo& rhs)` returns a *value*. That is, you don't return a reference to `tmp`, but a *copy of it*.

---

That's why an idiomatic `operator+` would return by value instead of by reference. You want:

```
// V no reference
Foo operator+(const Foo& rhs) { ... }
```

See also [this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) about canonical operator overloading.

Answer (score 1):

Your operator+ returns a reference to the temporary Foo called tmp. It will be automatically destroyed after the return.

You don't show a minimal, compilable example. But most likely, the assignment afterwards to f3 then fails.

The idiomatic approach for an operator+ is to return Foo by value.

```
// Note the missing & in the Foo return value
Foo operator+( const Foo& rhs )
{  
    Foo result( this->num + rhs.num, this->str + rhs.str );
    return result;
}
```